# Listing Files On Directory On a TListView

Tags: delphi, file-io, lazarus, tlistview

I'm building a program that needs to on `Form_Create`, populate a `TListView` called `FileList`, the directory that I want to populate is where the compiled program is + `\Files`, as I never used a `TListView` I want to know how to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are multiple parts to your question. I'll provide an *overview* here. If you need help on any particular step, please post a more specific follow-up question.

1. Determine what "where the compiled program is" refers to.

   To get the full path of the EXE file, call [`ParamStr(0)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.ParamStr). To remove the EXE file name from that string, so you have just the directory portion, call [`ExtractFilePath`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.ExtractFilePath). Make sure it ends with a backslash ([`IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter)) and then append your "Files" directory.
2. Get a list of files.

   Use [`FindFirst`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.FindFirst) and [`FindNext`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.FindNext) to make a loop that looks at all the files. The names will include the "." and ".." relative directory names, so you may wish to exclude them. Beware that the files are not enumerated in any particular order. If you need them sorted alphabetically, for instance, you'll need to do that yourself. (They may *appear* to be in alphabetical order in your tests, but that won't always be true.)

   ```
   var
     Rec: TSearchRec;
   begin
     if FindFirst(path + '\*', faAnyFile, Rec) = 0 then try
       repeat
         if (Rec.Name = '.') or (Rec.Name = '..') then
           continue;
         if (Rec.Attr and faVolumeID) = faVolumeID then
           continue; // nothing useful to do with volume IDs
         if (Rec.Attr and faHidden) = faHidden then
           continue; // honor the OS "hidden" setting
         if (Rec.Attr and faDirectory) = faDirectory then
           ; // This is a directory. Might want to do something special.
         DoSomethingWithFile(Rec.Name);
       until FindNext(Rec) <> 0;
     finally
       SysUtils.FindClose(Rec);
     end;
   end;
   ```
3. Add nodes to the control to represent the files.

   You might wish to do this in the hypothetical `DoSomethingWithFile` function I mentioned above. Use the list view's [`Items`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TCustomListView.Items) property to do things with the items, such as add new ones.

   ```
   var
     Item: TListItem;
   begin
     Item := ListView.Items.Add;
     Item.Caption := FileName;
   end;
   ```

   [`TListItem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TListItem) has additional properties; check the documentation for details. The [`SubItems`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TListItem.SubItems) property is useful if you're showing the list view in "report" mode, where there can be multiple columns for a single node.
4. Associate images with the items.

   Nodes' images in a list view come from the associated image lists, [`LargeImages`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TCustomListView.LargeImages) and [`SmallImages`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TCustomListView.SmallImages). They refer to one or more [`TImageList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TImageList) components on your form. Put your icon images there, and then assign the items' [`ImageIndex`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TListItem.ImageIndex) properties to the corresponding numbers.

Depending on how elaborate you want your program to be, you may wish to use Delphi's `TShellListView` control instead of doing all the above work yourself.

Comment: Great example of Stack Overflow in action. Really good answer Rob.

Answer (score 2):

If you drop a TImagelist on the form with two images in (one fore files and on for directories), then assign the TImagelist to the TListviews LargeImages property, you can use the below code.

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var li:TListItem;
    SR: TSearchRec;
begin
    FileList.Items.BeginUpdate;
    try
        FileList.Items.Clear;

        FindFirst(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) +'*.*', faAnyFile, SR);
        try
            repeat
                li :=  FileList.Items.Add;
                li.Caption := SR.Name;

                if ((SR.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0)  then li.ImageIndex := 1
                else li.ImageIndex := 0;

            until (FindNext(SR) <> 0);
        finally
            FindClose(SR);
        end;
    finally
        FileList.Items.EndUpdate;
    end;
end;
```

You can then build on this by adding different images to the TImageList for different file types, and using ExtractFileExt(SR.Name) to get the files extension

```
if ((SR.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0)  then li.ImageIndex := 1
else if lowercase(ExtractFileExt(SR.Name)) = '.png' then li.ImageIndex := 2
else if lowercase(ExtractFileExt(SR.Name)) = '.pdf' then li.ImageIndex := 3
else li.ImageIndex := 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to show the images when drawing the rows.

This should give you an idea:
http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=16
http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2008/qt/lv_checkbox_bmp.htm

The only difference is that you'll draw an icon/image.
Here you learn how to do it in a grid: http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa032205a.htm
So from both you can get the idea.